# Regex Redirect URL excludes token

Tags: java, regex, url, redirect, token

I'm trying to create a redirect URL for my client. We have a service that you specify `"fromUrl" -> "toUrl"` that is using a java regex Matcher. But I can't get it work to include the token in when it converts it. For example:

`/fromurl/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf`

Should be:

`/tourl/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf`

but it excludes the token so the result I get is:

`/fromurl/login/`

`/tourl/login/`

I tried various regex patterns like: `" ?.*` and `[%5E//?]+)/([^/?]+)/(?.*)?$`  and `(/*)` etc"  but no one seems to work.

I'm not that familiar with regex. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need something like this?

```
String from = "/my/old/url/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf";
String to = from.replaceAll("\\/(.*)\\/", "/my/new/url/");
System.out.println(to); // /my/new/url/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf";
```

This will replace everything between the first and the last forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using simple string replace but if you insist on using regular expressions:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("fromurl");
    String originalUrlAsString = "/fromurl/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf ";

String newRedirectedUrlAsString = p.matcher(originalUrlAsString).replaceAll("tourl");

    System.out.println(newRedirectedUrlAsString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you detail more exactly what the original expression is like? This is necessary because the regular expression is based on it.

Assuming that the first occurrence of **fromurl** should simply be replaced with the following code:

```
String from = "/fromurl/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf";
String to = from.replaceFirst("fromurl", "tourl");
```

But if it is necessary to use more complex rules to determine the substring to replace, you can use:

```
 String from = "/fromurl/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf";
 String to = "";
 String regularExpresion = "(<<pre>>)(fromurl)(<<pos>>)";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpresion);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(from);
 if (matcher.matches()) {
   to = from.replaceAll(regularExpresion, "$1tourl$3");
 }
```

**NOTE**: **pre** and **pos** targets are referencial because I don't know the real expresion of the url

**NOTE 2**: $1 and $3 refer to the first and the third group

Answer (score 0):

Although existing answers should solve the issue and some are similar, maybe below solution would be of help, with quite an easy regex being used (assuming you get input of same format as your example):

```
private static String replaceUrl(String inputUrl){
    String regex = "/.*(/login\\?token=.*)";
    String toUrl = "/tourl";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(inputUrl);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return toUrl + matcher.group(1);
    } else
        return null;
}
```

You can write a test if it works for other expected inputs/outputs if you want to change format and adjust regex:

```
    String inputUrl = "/fromurl/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf";
    String expectedUrl = "/tourl/login?token=7c8Q8grW5f2Kz7RP1%2FWsqpVB%2FEluVOGfXQdW4I0v82siR2Ism1D8VCvEmKJr%2BKhHhicwPey0uIiTxN049Be8TNsypf";
    if (expectedUrl.equals(replaceUrl(inputUrl))){
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
```